# JMeter custom Java sampler: how to access hashmap constructed in beanshell sampler?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have created a custom jmeter java sampler that sends requests to an HTTP endpoint in a loop and parses the responses.  Multiple threads are expected to run this sampler in a single thread group.

The requests are parameterized with an ID and I need every thread to lookup random name to ID mappings in a hashmap.  I would like to load the mapping from a csv file at the beginning of a test.

It was suggested that I might use a beanshell sampler inside of a setup thread group to read from the csv, create the hashmap, and store it in a JMeter property using something like `props.put()`.  Can someone tell me if this is a reasonable approach and if so, how do I access the particular JMeter property inside the custom sampler?

I found this answer: [Single thread initialization for Jmeter with multiple sampler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413181/single-thread-initialization-for-jmeter-with-multiple-sampler) which hints at what I'd like to do but does not provide details.

Answer (score -1):

It is, however [since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for any form of scripting.

So in [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) you can use `props.put('foo', myMap)` and in Java Request you can refer it like:

```
Map myMap = (HashMap)context.getJMeterProperties().get("foo");
```